# Configure Hosted Macos image

Tags: macos, azure-pipelines

Is there any way to manually configure a Hosted Macos agent in Azure Devops? I mean, download the agent, install several dependencies, applications, frameworks and utilities to build the application that I need and then upload this image to use it in my agent pool. As I can see, just only predefined agents with predefined softwares are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not able to do this. Software on Microsoft-hosted agents is updated once each month.

For detail software and frameworks on hosted Mac OS image you could refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Microsoft-hosted agents do not offer:

- The ability to log on.
- The ability to drop artifacts to a UNC file share.
- The ability to run XAML builds.
- Potential performance advantages that you might get by using
  self-hosted agents which might start and run builds faster.

If Microsoft-hosted agents don't meet your needs, then you should [deploy your own self-hosted MacOS agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops).